# XSLT transformation transfer child xlmns to parent

Tags: xslt

I am one input xml and I have the convert that using xslt to different format. MY input xml is

```
<ns2:getAllAreasResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dm.gov.ae/">
<return>
<ns3:Area xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
<ns3:Identity>451</ns3:Identity>
<ns3:NameAr>الحبيه الخامسة</ns3:NameAr>
<ns3:NameEn>Al Hebiah Fifth</ns3:NameEn>
</ns3:Area>
</return>
</ns2:getAllAreasResponse>
```

My output xml is like below

```
<ns2:getAllAreasResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dm.gov.ae/ xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
    <return>
    <ns3:Area ">
    <ns3:Identity>451</ns3:Identity>
    <ns3:NameAr>الحبيه الخامسة</ns3:NameAr>
    <ns3:NameEn>Al Hebiah Fifth</ns3:NameEn>
    </ns3:Area>
    </return>
    </ns2:getAllAreasResponse>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the input and the output (other than the misplaced quote in the output)?

Comment: The difference seems to be that the namespace declaration of ns3 has been promoted to the root element.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is probably:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <ns2:getAllAreasResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dm.gov.ae/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/EP4.Integration.Entities.Common">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node()"/>
  </ns2:getAllAreasResponse>
</xsl:template>
```